# Handling file/string encodings in Python library design

Tags: python, string, api, file-encodings

I am finishing up a new Python library which, among other things, can read and write files and strings in a specific format. I thought it would be nice if the read/write functions were equipped to handle different encodings. The library is expected to work on 2.7 and some of the 3.x versions.

Naturally, running `tox` afterwards blew up because of the different ways that Python's different versions handle encodings.

**My question is:** What is the best way to handle file/string encodings in Python API design?

Currently, I am considering letting the user handle all encoding except for my `write_string` function which will take a list of entries, an optional encoding (perhaps defaulting to utf-8) and format the string accordingly. This makes sense because the function takes a list of entries and not a string.

Comment: Always operate in `unicode`.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you mean assume that everything is in some form of unicode or that I should always stick with Python's unicode objects and not str types?